# how to get specific value from string array and save it to another string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

i have string array like this :
`String A[] = {"65535", "00000", "00000", "00000", "00000", "A32CE", "43251", "98702", "ACED2", "98AAB", "00000", "00000", "00000", "65535", "65535"}`

how to get the values other than `65535` and `00000` and save it to another string array like this:
`String B[] = {"A32CE", "43251", "98702", "ACED2", "98AAB"}`

I've already tried  this:

```
if(A!="65535" && A!="00000")
{
    for(i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    B[i] = A[i];
    }
}
```

but the return value that i get is the whole String A[]. Please help.

Comment: I've posted a solution will full code explanation. If you find it useful, please upvote it and mark it as your selected answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with arrays and not `ArrayList` objects, things get a little tedious. The following code runs through the first array, checks if the current `String` is not the one you don't want, and increases the counter by one if it has found one you do want. It then creates a new array as big as the number of objects you want in the initial array, runs through the intial array again, this time adding the `String` obejcts you want to the second array.

```
String[] arrayOne = {"65535", "00000", "00000", "00000", "00000",
        "A32CE", "43251", "98702", "ACED2", "98AAB",
        "00000", "00000", "00000", "65535", "65535"};

int validCounter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++)
  if(!(arrayOne[i].equals("65535") || arrayOne[i].equals("00000")))
      validCounter++;

String[] arrayTwo = new String[validCounter];
int arrayTwoPos = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++)
  if(!(arrayOne[i].equals("65535") || arrayOne[i].equals("00000"))){
      arrayTwo[arrayTwoPos] = arrayOne[i];
      arrayTwoPos++;
  }

for(int i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++)
    System.out.println(arrayTwo[i]);
```

Comment: Also make sure you return `arrayTwo`.